# Showing two fields from two tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to get an employee's first name and their department name (based on id_department). This is an example of my data:

[image: DEPARTMENTS TABLES]

[image: EMPLOYEES TABLES]

How would I accomplish this using MariaDB (shell)?

Comment: You'll want to learn about the `JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select FirstName, DepartmentName from Employees e inner join Department d on e.DepartmentId = e.DepartmentId
```

That's how we do it in SQL server side.

I just read the documentation of `MariaDB` and found that they have the exact same syntax for join. [Given example in their docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/join-syntax):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.b;
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answer your question. thanks

Comment: You might want to combine your other answer into this one (with a link to the documentation). Remember, Stack Overflow isn't a forum!